# Set date variable to null

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
 Dim dtIzvrsenja datetime
Private Sub chkDate_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkDate.CheckedChanged
        If Me.chkDate.Checked Then
            Me.dtpDate.CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
            Me.dtpDate.Enabled = True
            dtIzvrsenja = dtpdate.value
        Else
            Me.dtpDate.CustomFormat = " "
            Me.dtpDate.Enabled = False
            dtIzvrsenja = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
```

Is there any way to set the value of dtIzvrsenja to null if chk is not checked ?

Edit by using the way other mentioned.

> {"Nullable object must have a value."}

```
  Dim dtIzvrsenja2 As DateTime? = Nothing
            dtIzvrsenja = dtIzvrsenja2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to support that, you need to use the generic `Nullable(Of Date)` type rather than just `Date` (the VB alias for the `DateTime` type).  Normally, only *reference type* variables (`Class` type variables) support null values.  Since `Date` is a *value type* variable (`Structure`), it doesn't support null.  `Nullable(Of T)` allows you to wrap any *value type* and add support for null values to that type.

In VB (as well as C#, by the way), a question mark after any type name is shorthand for making the type nullable.  So, `Date?` is equivalent to `Nullable(Of Date)`.  Here's your example code using nullables:

```vb
Dim dtIzvrsenja As Date?
Private Sub chkDate_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkDate.CheckedChanged
    If Me.chkDate.Checked Then
        Me.dtpDate.CustomFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
        Me.dtpDate.Enabled = True
        dtIzvrsenja = dtpdate.value
    Else
        Me.dtpDate.CustomFormat = " "
        Me.dtpDate.Enabled = False
        dtIzvrsenja = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

However, the confusing thing about `Nullable(Of T)` is that it, itself, is not a *reference type*.  `Nullable(Of T)` is a *value type*.  So, even `Nullable(Of Date)` variables cannot be set to null in the traditional sense.  What `Nullable(Of T)` does is it adds a `HasValue As Boolean` property which allows you to check if the value is null.  Therefore, when you go to read the value of the variable, rather than first checking to see if the variable `Is Nothing`, you need to instead check to see if it's `HasValue` property is true.  For instance:

```vb
If dtIzvrsenja.HasValue Then
    Dim dtIzvrsenja2 As Date = dtIzvrsenja.Value
    ' ...
End If
```

If you really want to treat the `Date` type as a real reference type, then you can do so by declaring the variable `As Object`.  `Object` variables are always reference variables, so when set to `Nothing`, they really are set to null.  When you set an `Object` variable to a value-type value, such as a `Date`, it will *box* the value.  When you read it's value and convert it back to a `Date`, it will go through a process called *unboxing*.  This *boxing/unboxing* process does add some overhead, however.  Also, the other downside of this is that the type-checking for code working with the `Object` variable will be skipped at compile-time.  That means that, if you are not careful, you could get some exceptions at runtime if the variable references a type of object that is different than what you expect.  You could avoid the type-checking issue by declaring your own class:

```vb
Public Class DateReference
    Public Property Value As Date
End Class
```

Or:

```vb
Public Class Reference(Of T)
    Public Property Value As T
End Class
```

However, that seems silly.  `Nullable(Of T)` already serves that purpose, so unless you really need to make it a reference type, I'd suggest that you take the time to get acquainted with the standard way of doing it.

As a side note, another complication which further causes confusion in this area is that VB's `Nothing` keyword does not strictly mean null.  It just means the deafult value for any type.  So, for an `Integer`, `Nothing` equals the value zero.  For a `Date`, it means `Date.MinValue`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Nullable`:

```
Dim nullableDateValue As New Nullable(Of Date) = Nothing
```

Comment: But what if person check and uncheck the checkbox. I can't declare once again –

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the question mark (Nullable) specifier, though this is probably outmoded now...

```
Dim dtIzvrsenja As DateTime? = Nothing
```

Comment: But what if person check and uncheck the checkbox. I can't declare once again

Comment: Surely you can figure out a way of testing this? The most obvious way would be to have your own Structure to handle a date and Boolean if that's what you want, that way you don't even have to store a nothing.